# Channels not mapped when testing with Spring Cloud Stream using Spring Cloud Function

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am in the process of converting our existing stream processing code that currently uses the annotation-based programming model to use Spring Cloud Function instead. Using the test binder described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_test_binder_configuration), I am only able to successfully execute tests after creating a duplicate `@SpringBootApplication` static class following the example outlined [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_test_binder_usage) within my test that contains a duplicated `Consumer` function that I already defined in my `src/main/java/com/example/MySpringBootApplication` class.

If I try to reference my main `@SpringBootApplication` class in my test code via `@SpringBootTest(classes = {'MySpringBootApplication.class'})` and add `@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)` to the test as well, the `InputDestination` channel is not mapped, and the following stack trace is the result:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.AbstractDestination.getChannel(AbstractDestination.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.InputDestination.send(InputDestination.java:37)
    at com.example.stream.MyApplicationStreamProcessorIT.testSuccessfulMessageProcessing(MyApplicationStreamProcessorIT.java:172)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

My goal is to test the `@SpringBootApplication` defined under `src/main/java` and not have to duplicate my `@Bean`s in a test class in order to test my code. Is this duplication required as part of the Test Binder configuration, or is there something else I need to do in order to test my main class and not duplicate any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it doesn't work for you, but here is the complete test

- in src/main

```
package foo.bar;

import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
        return v -> v.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

- in src/test

```
package foo.bar;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.InputDestination;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.OutputDestination;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.TestChannelBinderConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
public class SampleApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    InputDestination input;
    
    @Autowired
    OutputDestination output;
    
    @Test
    public void loadContext() {
        input.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("blah").build());
        System.out.println(new String(output.receive().getPayload()));
    }
}
```

You should see `BLAH` in your console

Comment: I figured out what the source of the problem was. As we are currently using the annotation-based programming model, to get our integration tests working properly, we found we had to add the following exclusion: ```@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ContextFunctionCatalogAutoConfiguration.class})```. Without that, our integration tests fail. Once I removed that exclusion, I was able to set up my tests just as your example outlines, which is what I tried in the first place. Actually, if you add the same exclusion to your example, the test fails with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The critical clue for me was found in the startup-log of the test:

```
Multiple functional beans were found [uppercase, sendToDlqAndContinue], thus can't determine default function definition. Please use 'spring.cloud.function.definition' property to explicitly define it.
```

This basically means, spring does not know, which functional bean to bind to the InputDestination and OutputDestination. So it does nothing and no channel is available.
Consequently:
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`
while trying to access "the first channel".

So the following worked for me:

In src/main/java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.function.Function;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleStreamProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleStreamProcessor.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String,String> uppercase() {
        return v -> v.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

in src/test/java:

```
import 
io.github.oliverjurkschat.kafkastreamstestapp.uppercase.SampleStreamProcessor;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.InputDestination;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.OutputDestination;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.TestChannelBinderConfiguration;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest(classes = {SampleStreamProcessor.class, TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath*:test.properties")
public class SampleStreamProcessorTests {

    @Autowired
    private InputDestination input;

    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination output;

    @Test
    public void testEmptyConfiguration() {
        this.input.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("hello").build());
        assertThat(output.receive().getPayload()).isEqualTo("HELLO".getBytes());
    }

}
```

test.properties:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=uppercase
```

This detail **can be found at** https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/spring-cloud-stream/spring_integration_test_binder.html#test-binder-usage in the **2nd code-snippet**.
Although they recommend to insert the system-property programmatically.
The first example in that doc still fails.